# JSON response in Laravel 5.5 adds additional fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to return JSON in a controller using this line:

```
return response()->json( $return );
```

`$return` contains two key/value pairs.

When I try to validate the response in a test, it fails because the response does contain additional fields:

```
Unable to find JSON:

[{
    "statusCode": 665,
    "msg": "auth missing"
}]

within response JSON:

[{
    "headers": [],
    "original": {
        "statusCode": "665",
        "msg": "auth missing"
    },
    "exception": null
}].
```

I have no idea how the additional keys get there and why the source array is nested in the `source` key.

How can I make sure that only the array that I pass to `response()->json` is returned?

Comment: Could you post the test file, you should be authenticated from what I can tell

Comment: In short, you are converting an object to JSON, not just 2 data points. you can get round this by using ->get(); on you DB call which will make it return an array, then turn that into JSON OR keep the call the same and assign the specific data point to your return function e.g. return response()->json([$return->statusCode, $return->msg] );

Comment: try `return response($return , 200);`

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here:

The problem was that `$return` was already a json encoded object. So this weird formatting is the result of converting json into json.